# lua module is not loading libraries

Tags: module, lua

### Background Information:

I'm just new to lua and I'm trying to understand how modules work. But I'm trying to load a pre-existing module into a new script and run this script from the command line.

### Code:

I have a file called main.lua module that looks something like this:

```
module (..., package.seeall)
-- Load libraries
require("luasql.postgres")
require("luasql.sqlite3")

local connect_to_db = function()
   if not global_con then
      env = assert (luasql.postgres())
      global_con = assert (env:connect(databasename, databaseUser, databasepassword, databaseserver))   
      return true
   else
      return false 
   end
end

update_widget = function (parm1, parm2, parm3)
  local connected = connect_to_db()         
  if connected then
     -- do something else
     return true
  end
end -- end function.
```

I'm now trying to create a test script for this module.  I have the following logic in a separate lua file:

```
package.path = '/usr/share/myapp/main.lua;'
local my_object = require("main")

print my_object.update_widget
```

### Problem:

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my test script:

```
attempt to call field 'postgres' (a table value)
```

The line it's failing on is in the connect_to_db() method where I try to create an environment variable:

```
env = assert (luasql.postgres())
```

### What I've Tried so far:

1. I've modified the `package.path` in my test script to match what is being used by main.lua.  I did so by executing main.lua the "regular" way - driven by a web app - and dumping out the contents of `package.path` to a log file. 
   I've copied the path from the log file and used it as the `package.path` value in my test script... of course, I had to modify it by adding an additional entry - a path leading to main.lua.
   But other than that, the package paths are the same.
2. I've added print statements inside main.lua to prove that it is getting into the update_widget method... and that it's just failing trying to create the postgres.
3. I've added the luasql.postgres library in the test script to see if that would help... like so:

   ```
   package.path = '/var/x/appname/main.lua;'

   local pgdb = require("luasql.posgres")

   print(pgdb)
   myenv = assert(lua.postgres()) -- fails
   ```

The test script also dies trying to create this object... I'm going to keep hunting around.  It must be a problem with the paths... but I can't see the difference between the path thats created when loaded by the web app, vs. what I have in the test script. 
I'm going to use a DIFF tool to compare for now.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I definitely think it's the path, although I can't see just yet what's wrong with here. 
I created yet another test script (let's call it test3).. but this time, I didn't explicitly  set the path by assigning values to package.path. 
I just tried to include the luasql.postgres pacakge and use it the way the original test script does... and it works!
So here's code that works:

```
luasql = require "luasql.postgres"
local myenv = assert (luasql.postgres())
print(myenv)
```

But this fails:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';/usr/share/myapp/main.lua'

luasql = require "luasql.postgres"
myenv = assert (luasql.postgres())
print(myenv)
```

Also to greatwolf's point, I tried from interactive mode in lua... and my code works just fine.

```
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> pgdb = require("luasql.postgres")
> print(pgdb)
table: 0x176cb228
> myenv=assert(luasql.postgres())
> print(myenv)
PostgreSQL environment (0x176c9d5c)
>
```

So... here's the package.path variable from interactive mode:

```
> print(package.path)
./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua
>
```

And here's the path from my original test script where it fails.

> /usr/share/myapp/main.lua;./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua

Comment: Can you test this through a lua interpreter or repl and see what `luasql.postgres` is returning back? According to [**github repo**](https://github.com/keplerproject/luasql/blob/master/src/ls_postgres.c#L601) `postgres` itself should be a function.

Comment: greatwolf, please see my edit 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a problem with the path.  I'm still not sure exactly what was wrong, but I changed my logic in the test script from:

```
package.path = '/usr/share/myapp/main.lua;' -- resetting package path manually
package.path=package.path ..'./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua
```

'

to

```
package.path = package.path .. '/usr/share/myapp/main.lua' -- append to default path.
```

Now it finds the lua postgres package and lets me call the functions too

Comment: Out of curiosity what if you tried prepending like this `package.path = '/usr/share/myapp/main.lua;' .. package.path`?

Comment: After some testing, it's becoming clear what's happening. `require` considers `package.path` in the order from left to right. For each given path it checks if the file exist, if it does then that is used and the rest of the paths aren't considered for that module.

Comment: For `/usr/share/myapp/main.lua;` since it doesn't have `?` lua will search literally for that file whenever you `require` a module. In other words, specifying the path for `main.lua` like that acts as a "catch-all" default. Since it appears first before all the other paths, this is the one that ends up getting used during module load.

Answer (score 2):

When Lua executes `require "luasql.postgres"` it tries to find postgres.lua in `luasql` folder anywhere in its `LUA_PATH`, loads it, and executes it, thereby putting any non-local variables (including functions) appearing at module level of `postgres.lua` in the global namespace. The `main.lua` you show is requiring a module then using it as a function: `luasql.postgres()`. This will only work if some trick is used. For instance, if the loaded module returns a function, you could use

```
fn = require 'luasql.postgres'
fn()
```

to execute the function returned.

Also, unlike python where you can import items from within a module, in Lua you can't. So it's not like postgres could be a function or callable table.

If you replace `main.lua` with the following,

```
require 'luasql.postgres'
luasql.postgres()
```

and run your test script, or run `main.lua` directly, you should get an error. If you don't, the module is definitely doing something special to support this use.

If you change your `main.lua` as above and it doesn't work, then neither can you do

```
env = assert (luasql.postgres())
```

but you could do any of these, depending on what `postgres.lua` does:

```
env = assert (luasql.postgres)
env = assert (someFunctionDefinedInPostgresModule)
env = assert (someFunctionDefinedInPostgresModule())
env = assert (luasql.postgres.someFunction)
env = assert (luasql.postgres.someFunction())
```

Comment: Can whoever downvoted at least put a comment stating why? I'm puzzled as to how this wouldn't be the answer, and curious to find out what I'm missing.

Comment: Schollii, I downvoted because of the comment that you cannot call luasql.postgres().  That is a legit function call.  If I misunderstood your comment please let me know!  I'd be happy to undo my downvote!

Comment: Also, I know that modules are just tables...but I'm interested in your comment about not having " __call".  Can you explain a bit further or point me to an article to find out more?  Thanks.

Comment: @dot I don't see how it can be legit unless postgres.lua is doing something special. I've updated my answer, if you can try what's there that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @dot I just looked at your edit and the code that worked is different from what you had at top: in your edit you have luasql=require 'luasql.postgres', in that case of course it can work, that's even one of the things I explain in my answer. So I don't feel that a downvote is appropriate here.