# C++ program using torch compiles, but cannot load libtorch.so at runtime

Tags: c++, lua, torch

I am using C++ code that integrates torch and runs lua scripts internally. I have compiled and installed torch and torch is running successfully. As such, the c++ project compiles and produces executables with no errors.

At run time, the code receives lua script name as a parameter, and tries to execute this script. This lua script alone runs via torch, i.e. th script.lua runs and shows no errors. However within the code I get a runtime error: /home/jeffrey/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:13: cannot load '/home/jeffrey/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/libtorch.so'.

I have tried removing libtorch.so from the directory and then I get an error that the library cannot be found so the problem is that it cannot be loaded and I am not exactly sure what this means. I tried giving additional permissions to all the libraries in my torch installation as superuser - this did not work.

I am running the executable as follows:

../../train_obj -oscript train_obj.lua

where train_obj is the executable and train_obj.lua is the script that is going to be run.
In the script, there are require statements to include modules from torch. When "require" is called, init.lua is triggered.

In init.lua on lines 12 and 13 the following require statements appear:

(line 12) require "paths"

(line 13) paths.require "libtorch"

Line 13 apparently tries to load the libtorch library, i.e. libtorch.so.
At this line, at run time, the above error occurs.

I am having difficulty troubleshooting what to do to enable this library to load at runtime. Again - if I directly use torch via the th statement and call either:
th train_obj.lua
or:
th init.lua
everything is fine - both run without error.
Only when I run train_obj.lua through the code, which causes init.lua to be run, do I get the error loading the library. 
If anyone has experienced this and has understood what is needed to enable loading the library, I'd appreciate assistance with this issue.

Comment: Seems related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644731/lua-module-is-not-loading-libraries

Comment: Well - it turns out, Elias, that it had to do with the way that lib tiff and opencv (and some other small stuff) were linked. For a variety of reasons, these libs were taken from anaconda and not from the standard installation places. Once I forced them to be taken from the standard places, everything ran well and the libtorch library was loaded. 
Actually your comment helped me a lot to get a grip of the problem and delve into the answer so I want to thank you very much.
Jeff